# Efficient hash function for memory addresses

Tags: c, memory, hash, hashmap

I want to implement a kind of "smart" malloc, that would keep allocated memory in a data structure so it is easy to free everything in a row. I think the best data structure for that kind of problem would be a **Hash Map**.

So I would like to know what kind of Hash Function would fit the best this problem (maybe something around bitwise operations since it will hash addresses?).

*One more thing: I cannot use **any** library (other than libc) and the less already existing function it uses, the better*

Feel free to suggest any other data structure or idea that would be better than mine.

Thanks

Comment: What makes your `malloc` smarter than the existing implementations?

Comment: It's not smarter than the existing one but it would allow me to be sure there is absolutely no memory leak (which is the final goal)

Comment: (A new malloc won't fix incorrect paring of allocation/free - there are existing tools that can help track down memory issues.)

Comment: Anyway, .NET and Java and Python provide a default "hash" function for objects by their internal reference/or-whatever-they-use (with very little, if any, extra magic). This hash function probably the least useful concern in the implementation. It will be 'good enough' if it's reasonably distributed.

Comment: Have you seen [mimalloc from Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/mimalloc)? It's a new malloc implementation that's a substantial improvement over all the popular allocators. If you're running into memory allocation overhead, try using it instead.

Comment: I'll clarify my post about that but I cannot use any library (except the libc) and the less existing functions it uses, the better

Comment: Write code that doesn't leak memory in the first place?

Comment: @Shawn - What if it's not his code?

Comment: Honestly I don't entirely understand your goal here. If the goal is to manage memory then just use shared_ptr, unique_ptr, etc., or your own implementation if you can't use those. If your goal is to increase the efficiency of memory allocations then you should probably allocate in large blocks, determined through some algorithm that finds the optimum block size. Note that HeapAlloc in Windows is already a built in mechanism that (sort of) does this. I'm not familiar with Linux but I'm sure they have something similar.